# In my Go Code, why does outer for loop run twice

Tags: go

Why does this code run the outer for loop twice?

Here is my code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    loops := 1
    for loops > 0 {
        fmt.Printf("\nNo of loops\n")
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &loops)
        for i := 0; i < loops; i++ {
            fmt.Printf("%d ", i)
        }
    }

}
```

When I run and enter 1 for number of loops, here is the output:

```
No of loops
0 
No of loops
0 
No of loops
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you look at the [How to Scan](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Scanning) in the documentation
It says

> Scan, Fscan, Sscan treat newlines in the input as spaces.

I have tried the below code

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    loops := 1
    for loops > 0 {
        fmt.Printf("\nNo of loops\n")
        temp := 1
        fmt.Scanf("%d %d", &loops, &temp)
        fmt.Println("Temp:", temp)
        for i := 0; i < loops; i++ {
            fmt.Printf("\ti: %d \n", i)
        }
    }

}
```

I created a temp var and scanned from the os.Stdin as above.

The output for loops=1 was

```
Loop: 1
No of loops
1
Temp: 1
        i: 0
Loop: 1
No of loops
```

and so temp took out the new line, the outer loop executed as expected.

Without temp variable, the flow was like

```
-> loops=1 
-> outer for 
-> scanf loops (as 1) 
-> inner for loop 
-> outer for 
-> scanning will be ignored. since buffer is present in Standard Input, i.e., new line.
-> inner for loop
```

That is we are seeing two inner loops for loops=1. This is not only for loops=1 but for any value of loops will give you 2 inner for loop.

You prevent this as above in the code or you can use [Scanln](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fscanln) Method.

> Scanln is similar to Scan, but stops scanning at a newline and after the final item there must be a newline or EOF.

Something like this should do

```
fmt.Scanln(&loops)
```